# How to search results using awk command in .CSV file

Tags: unix, awk, grep

I've a CDR file(.CSV) which contains around 150 columns and is a very large file. I'm trying to get the output where the 31st column should have value "13".

I'm trying with below command:

```
awk -F',' '$31~/^13/' report_1.csv > report_2.csv
```

But getting the following error:

```
awk: record `,1402786,535,1,47432... has too many fields record number 1`
```

Any help?

Comment: Which version of `awk` are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest:

```
awk -F',' '$31 == "13"' report_1.csv > report_2.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

The limit on number of fields shouldn't be so low as 150, so I'm guessing you're **probably not parsing your CSV file properly**.

If a particular, you should not split on just any comma - you should avoid splitting on `,` within quoted fields (`"like,this"`).

If you're using GNU `awk`, proper CSV parsing is pretty simple via [`FPAT`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Splitting-By-Content) (according to [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45420607/404556) by @Ed Morton):

```
awk -v FPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]+"' '$31 ~ /^13/' file
```

or, for an exact match:

```
awk -v FPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]+"' '$31 == "13"' file
```

In a non-GNU `awk` case, refer to the cited answer for an alternative parsing method.

Comment: Thanks for this....I need to ask if I want the output where 31st column as "13", 56th column as "ABC" and the 80th column, what should be the awk command?

Comment: Simply combine the conditions: ' $31 == "13" && $56 == "ABC" && $80 ~ /.../ '.

Comment: @User123, I see you already asked this in a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47113325/trying-to-get-the-results-using-awk) before I was able to answer your comment :) Anyhow, does this answer help you, and/or does it solve the initial problem you had?

Answer (score 0):

Some implementations of `awk` come with a maximum number of columns. `mawk` for example. You can test this easily by assigning to `NF`, like this:

```
$ mawk 'BEGIN{NF=32768}'
mawk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767
        FILENAME="" FNR=0 NR=0
```

To walk around this, you can use GNU awk, `gawk`, which does not have such an explicit limit.

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{NF=32768}'
$ gawk 'BEGIN{NF=1000000}'
```

Well, it is still limited by the amount of available memory. (But that should allow you to have at least millions of fields on a normal pc).

PS: You might need to install `gawk` and of course, processing such large files might be slow.